# jsPdf generates high quality image gives uncaught exception: Provided element is not within a Document

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf-generation, jspdf, html2canvas

I am trying to save a PDF file using jsPdf and htmlcanvas2 in reactjs. The code segment is resided inside a react Modal window. I am embedding an HTML template inside the Modal body generated by pebble-engine which is needed to be saved as a PDF.

I have tried jspdf with the quality parameter for a high-quality image.

- https://itnext.io/javascript-convert-html-css-to-pdf-print-supported-very-sharp-and-not-blurry-c5ffe441eb5e

But without the 'quality' parameter it works fine and gives a low quality image.

Following is the code segment I have tried.

```
printTest =(quality = 2) =>{
        const filename  = 'quotation.pdf';
        //let element11 = document.querySelector("#print-div")[0];
        let base64txt = this.b64EncodeUnicode(this.quotationTemplate);

        html2canvas(base64txt,
            {scale: quality}
        ).then(canvas => {
            let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
            pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'), 'JPEG', 0, 0, 211, 298, 'someAlias', 'FAST');
            pdf.save(filename);
        });
    };

    b64EncodeUnicode = (str) =>{
        return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g,
            function toSolidBytes(match, p1) {
                return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
            }));
    };

    b64DecodeUnicode =(str)=> {
        return decodeURIComponent(atob(str).split('').map(function(c) {
            return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
        }).join(''));
    };
```

Inside the React Modal, the  need to parameter is included as follows.

```
....
            <Modal.Body>
                <div id="print-div" className="print-div" ref={r => this.quotationTemplate = r}>
                        {parse(this.state.evaluatedTemplate)}
                    </div>
            <Modal.Footer> ....
```

When it runs in the browser, it gives the error as `uncaught exception: Provided element is not within a Document`.

Is this because the `<div>` is residing inside a Modal?